# Use count and case together using SQL

Tags: sql-server, group-by, count, case, distinct

I want to use a query to return 3 columns, how many type-A blood patients are patient sets,
how many type-B blood patients are there, and how many countries are there based on patients.

Each patient is identified using an unique ID, so patientID is what I'm doing count on. Each State is just using state abbreviation and blood type just letters.

And there are sets of patients, sets are just group of patients lumped together, so like a bunch of patientIDs, they are also unique like patientsID

So far I have something like this, I don't want to use SUM because that would add each patientsID numbers together, I should be using Count. Is there way to count using a case scenario? Or is there better way to accomplish what I want?

```
select distinct PTID,
select count (patientID CASE WHEN bloodtype = 'A') as totalAbloodtype, 
select count (patientID CASE WHEN bloodtype = 'AB') as totalABbloodtype,
select count  (distinct countrycode) as totalcountriesinset
from patientsinfo 
and PTID is not null
group by PTID
```

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: You need to show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sum` with a `case expression`. You don't need `distinct` with `group by` and you seem to be missing `where` with an abundance of `selects` so the code you have will just be a syntax error.

Obviously with no sample data or desired results I cannot test, but the idea is

```
select PTID,
sum (CASE WHEN bloodtype = 'A'  then 1 else 0 end) as totalAbloodtype, 
sum (CASE WHEN bloodtype = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end) as totalABbloodtype,
count (distinct countrycode) as totalcountriesinset
from patientsinfo 
where PTID is not null
group by PTID
```